# Convert CSV file to Excel format in VB2012

Tags: excel, vb.net, csv

I have a csv file created by my VB application and I want to convert it to Excel format (.xlsx).
Can please anybody help me with that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
        // input and output files
        string csv = @"c:\data\input.csv";
        string xls = @"c:\data\output.xlsx";

        // init the Appl obj
        Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();

        // get the worksheet
        Excel.Workbook wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(csv);
        Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        // select the used range
        Excel.Range used = ws.UsedRange;

        // autofit the columns
        used.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

        // save as xlsx
        wb.SaveAs(xls, 51);

        wb.Close();
        xl.Quit();
```